# Django: removing m2m relation in object

Tags: python, django, django-models

I just started playing with Django, I love it! I am still working my way around with the Django ORM though...

At the moment I have a model Shift with a m2m relationship with users:

```
class Shift(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

I want to define a view that checks if a M2M relationship exists, if it does, it removes this relationship. This is where I am stuck: I am able to lookup if a relationship exists, but I am not able to remove it. What is wrong with my code?

```
def remove_if_exists(request, shift_id, username):
    shift = get_object_or_404(Shift, pk=shift_id)
    if shift.users.filter(username=username).exists()
        shift.users.remove(username)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble with your code is that the relationship is not with a username, but with a User object. So your call to `remove` should have a User object as its argument. You need to actually get the relevant user from the db first, then call remove with that object.

However, there is a shortcut: remove does not raise an error if the object is not in the related set, so you can skip the exists call. That gives just:

```
user = User.objects.get(username=username)
shift = get_object_or_404(Shift, pk=shift_id)
shift.users.remove(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some stupid syntax mistake of my own, should be:

```
 shift.users.remove(User.objects.get(username=username))
```